# constructor of methods chain (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
private IEnumerable<EventSchedule> GetTodaySchedules(string tab)
{
    var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var result = Database.EventSchedules.Where(s => 
    s.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today && 
    s.RecurrenceStart.Value.TimeOfDay > today.TimeOfDay &&
    s.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today &&
    s.BaseEvent.EndShow > DateTime.Now &&
    s.BaseEvent.IsApproved.Value && !s.IsRemoved.Value &&
    s.BaseEvent.EventsCategories.Any(c => c.EventCategory.Name == tab)).ToList();
}
```

This query select today events from `EventSchedule` table. The problem in that, sometimes `tab` is empty and this query return no records. I can write something like that:

```
private IEnumerable<EventSchedule> GetTodaySchedules(string tab)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tab))
        {
             var result = Database.EventSchedules.Where(s => 
             s.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today && 
             s.RecurrenceStart.Value.TimeOfDay > today.TimeOfDay &&
             s.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today &&
             s.BaseEvent.EndShow > DateTime.Now &&
             s.BaseEvent.IsApproved.Value && !s.IsRemoved.Value).ToList();
        {
        else
        {
             var result = Database.EventSchedules.Where(s => 
             s.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today && 
             s.RecurrenceStart.Value.TimeOfDay > today.TimeOfDay &&
             s.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today &&
             s.BaseEvent.EndShow > DateTime.Now &&
             s.BaseEvent.IsApproved.Value && !s.IsRemoved.Value &&
             s.BaseEvent.EventsCategories.Any(c => c.EventCategory.Name == tab)).ToList();
        }

    }
```

but it's ugly. There is a other way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about this... you could ternary operator like shown by Henrik too...

```
private IEnumerable<EventSchedule> GetTodaySchedules(string tab)
{
     var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
     var result = Database.EventSchedules.Where(s => 
     s.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today && 
     s.RecurrenceStart.Value.TimeOfDay > today.TimeOfDay &&
     s.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today &&
     s.BaseEvent.EndShow > DateTime.Now &&
     s.BaseEvent.IsApproved.Value && !s.IsRemoved.Value);
     if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tab))
     {
         var result1 = result.Where(s => s.BaseEvent.EventsCategories.Any(c => c.EventCategory.Name == tab))).ToList();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
&& (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tab) || s.BaseEvent.EventsCategories.Any(c => c.EventCategory.Name == tab))
```

BTW, use IsNullOrWhiteSpace